# iOS RxSwift how to “pull” from Observable.of(1,2,3)?

Tags: recursion, ios11, rx-swift

Im working on RX swift problem to emulate 4 user taps. The requirement is to have them happen asynchronously in response to other events within RX. So I cannot use timers or intervals.

I’m thinking of a function that would “pull” from an  observable that can emit up to 4 values, then terminate. My question is :

**What operator allows me to “pull” or step through all elements of an observable from start to finish?**

```
func recursive(duration: int) -> Observable<Int>
{
// logic that may terminate recursion based on network conditions

//logic to terminate if number of taps exceeded
If I take from the taps array observable, and it completes - terminate recursion
}
```

The idea is to try to make a “pure” RX implementation, without relying on external variables. Im thinking of `Zip`, but am struggling to see how it is related to the recursive nature of the solution

Comment: Can you draw up a marble diagram of the inputs and outputs? Then we can figure the logic that goes in the function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, I did something like that using promises a few years ago. Maybe it could help you. https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/2b19e59beaf480535596

Below, I have updated the promise code to use `Single`s:

```
/**
Repeatedly evaluates a promise producer until a value satisfies the predicate.
`promiseWhile` produces a promise with the supplied `producer` and then waits
for it to resolve. If the resolved value satisfies the predicate then the
returned promise will fulfill. Otherwise, it will produce a new promise. The
method continues to do this until the predicate is satisfied or an error occurs.

- Returns: A promise that is guaranteed to fulfill with a value that satisfies
the predicate, or reject.
*/

func doWhile<T>(pred: @escaping (T) -> Bool, body: @escaping () -> Single<T>, fail: (() -> Single<Void>)? = nil) -> Single<T> {
    return Single.create { event in
        func loop() {
            _ = body().subscribe(onSuccess: { (t) -> Void in
                if !pred(t) {
                    event(SingleEvent.success(t))
                }
                else {
                    if let fail = fail {
                        _ = fail().subscribe(onSuccess: { loop() }, onError: { event(SingleEvent.error($0)) })
                    }
                    else {
                        loop()
                    }
                }
            }, onError: {
                event(SingleEvent.error($0))
            })
        }
        loop()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

I don't expect you would be able to just use the above, but hopefully you can draw inspiration from it.

Comment: It’s very much like we are trying to implement time delayed loops in RX

Comment: That sounds like the `sample` operator.